# Is it possible to "hack into" the unobtrusive validaton supported in ASP.NET MVC 3?

Tags: jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations, unobtrusive-javascript

I want to be able to use the built-in, data-annotation based, client-side unobtrusive  validation, but do my own ajax form submission after I know it passes.

Something like this jQuery bit:

```
$('#form').submit(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  if (PassesUnobtrusiveValidation()) {
    // ajax submit form
  }
});
```

Is there a `PassedValidation` event, or something like it, (built into the default, asp.net mvc 3 data-annotation based client side validation) I can hook into (like the psuedocode in the example)?

I want to do this so I can still take advantage of the data-annotation based validation, and then submit the form asynchronously how I want to. I wish to avoid writing common validation in the client, letting asp.net mvc 3 take care of it for me, and then submitting the form how I want to, using `$.ajax();`

Comment: why do you want to do this? =)

Comment: question updated to reflect why... ;)

Comment: I don't understand your question :3

Comment: true, still unclear what you want to do? Example? What advantage do you want? There are ways to add your own javascript validators.

Comment: I want the built-in asp.net mvc 3 unobtrusive validation to do the validation work, and if it passes (i.e., `PassesUnobtrusiveValidation()` psuedocode in the question), I want to submit the form using jQuery.ajax() (and do some other work as well).

Comment: I want to avoid adding my own javascript validators. I want to use the data-annotation based validation provided in asp.net mvc 3.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you are using jquery.validate:

```
$('#myForm').submit(function() {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        // Client side validation passed => submit the form
    }
});
```

Another possibility is to hook at the plugin [options](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options):

```
$.validator.setDefaults({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        // Client side validation passed => submit the form
    }
});
```

If you are using MSAjax then good luck with this.

Comment: awesome, I am using the jQuery validate version. I didn't even think about that... thanks. I'll try this out, but it looks like it should work! Much appreciated.