# jQuery Validation Problem using MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-validate

My problem is I am using the MVC3's feature of unobtrusive client side validation but I need to hook into it and add a function that fires on a successful validation but before the form is posted.

I'm hoping there is some pre-built helper or an easy way to hook into the validator.

Here's a code snippet:

```
    @using (Html.BeginForm("MyAction","MyController")) {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
        <fieldset> <legend><legend>
        <label for="FirstName">First Name</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up needing to hook into the validation process to perform my own custom validation and also do some div collapsing. Here's a snippet of jQuery that accomplished what I needed:

```
    //Hijack the submit event to do custom validation and collapse the div
    $('#theFormName').submit(function () {
        var customErrorHandling = false;

        //do some custom validation

        if (customerErrorHandling == false) {

            //Now do the jQuery validation
            if ($('#theFormName').valid()) {

                //do some div collapsing

                $('#theFormName').unbind('submit');
                $('#theFormName').submit();
            }
        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

try these articles...

http://devtrends.co.uk/blog/the-complete-guide-to-validation-in-asp.net-mvc-3-part-2

http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2010/10/mvc3-unobtrusive-validation.html

[Is it possible to "hack into" the unobtrusive validaton supported in ASP.NET MVC 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5295412/is-it-possible-to-hack-into-the-unobtrusive-validaton-supported-in-asp-net-mvc)

hope these help you ...

thanks